# Doppler effect in long distance communication using 868MHz band for telemetry signals

Tags: quadcopter, communication, swarm

I am working on a project which involves multiple quadcopters working about 5 km away from the ground control station. The communication is planned to be done using RFD868+ modules on each of the drones from jdrones. When these quadcopters are in motion, will there be packet loss in the telemetry commands sent to the individual quadcopters due to the doppler effect? I believe there should not be any issue as the velocity of the quadcopters is miniscule when compared to the speed of light. Am i right ?

Also when multiple quadcopters are trying to communicate using this system, is there any alternative to CSMA CD ? (It is in a mesh topology)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Nikhil Khedekar. Questions are free, so if you have multiple questions, especially unrelated ones, please split them up into their own posts. Questions about networking or network topologies might be better asked at [cs.se].

Answer (score 1):

You are totally right, the speed of the drones is ridiculous when compared to the speed of light, thus the *relativistic* doppler effect is totally neglegible. Nevertheless, you may encounter communication problems due to the distance at which they are operating, which causes signal degradation, and due to interference, which may be relevant with the high amplification that you are gonna need in order to receive at that distance.

About the other question I don't know, but that might be material for another post, since it's just vaguely related with the title.